# Best platform for Bluetooth Applications

Tags: iphone, android, ios, bluetooth, mobile-phones

Which Mobile Application platform do developers prefer for Bluetooth Based application development ?

What do developers think on the current available API's on these platforms ? Does it meet most of your needs ?
What kinds of APIs / capabilities for applications would you like to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone is a bit locked down for general Bluetooth connections. Between iPhones it's easy, using GameKit. Between iPhone and headset is also, as I understand it, easy. But when it comes to talking to an arbitrary device over BT you need to use the External Accessory framework. This is fine and easy to use, but you need to be connecting to an Apple-licensed device. For the project I've been working on, this was fine because we control the BT device that we're connecting to. But in other cases, this limitation could be a serious negative.