# Android Tablet or iPad for Kiosk Device

Tags: android, ios, ipad, tablet

We want to place a device in a store that operates as sort of a kiosk device.  As in customers walk up to it and start interacting with our custom app.  The app could be developed for Android or the iPad, so I'm trying to decide which one to use and would like comments on the following ideas:

- Is it possible for Android or iOS to access services over the USB port?  This would enable us to disable the network.
- Is one particularly better for 24 hour always on?
- I like the iPad as I think its supply will be more constant as we move forward and need to replace devices due to ones gone bad.  Also, our app will probably work on future generations of the iPad.  With Android, I'm not sure there will be that sort of consistency from the tablet vendors.
- Kiosk mode?  I think with the iPad by putting it in a kiosk case that removes access to the home button and turning on the restrictions we'll get what we want.  What about Android?  I'd rather not have to get into rooting devices and replacing their firmware.
- Remote control?  Any way to remotely control iOS or Android in a standard means?  Our app will be a client to a master server which will obviously be able to control the app somewhat (when used purely as a display device to a customer, controlled from behind the counter).

My feeling is that neither Android tablets or the iPad is best suited for this.  Are there other options?

Comment: Is there any particular reason they want to use a tablet vs some other embedded PC device? A quick Google later, most of the kiosk hardware I'm seeing 700-800 dollars for the hardware, start with any tablet, then add the cabinet et all, I can't see it being much if any less expensive.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer your points, but know that I am probably biased towards Android, because that is where my experience lies.

- With Android 3.1+, at least with the Xoom, you have full USB host capabilities. Things like USB flash/hard drives, keyboards, mice, even digital cameras, all work. If you need custom interop with a USB device, you could go as far as to write a driver for it.
- 24 hour always on is not good for any device with a battery, but neither is better in this situation.
- While android apps are forward-compatible, bad programming practices and/or deviations from "vanilla" Android software and hardware CAN break forward compatibility. That being said, if you grab a Google Experience device like the Xoom, you won't meet as many surprises.
- In Android 3.0, the navigation bar is built-in at a low level, and it is not possible for apps to remove it. Therefore, it is trivial for anyone to break a "software nanny."
- I know that it is possible to control android devices remotely, but without knowing your specific needs, I can't really offer more information than that.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I wanted to run my android app in a kiosk device which has touch feature, Its like when my app is displaying in kiosk device, I should be able to operate with touch, just like how I use it in my phone or tablet can this be possible ? please suggest

Answer (score 2):

iPad NOOO believe me I am a convert to Apple for my home and business but when we went to launch kiosk the iPad FAILED Big Time.. Here are a couple of little (Big) issues we ran into.

1. If the device reboots you cannot auto launch you iPad app since Apple does not allow that.
2. There is a serious memory leak in the iPads browser. We were running javascript / CSS3 and it cratered intermittently. I literally spent 2 hours "today" on the phone with Apple getting the MAJOR run around. I finally said let me speak to an Enterprise Sales Manager as my project could mean thousands of iPads and I got NO WHERE. One Apple employee even told me they don't have enterprise sales managers.

If those weren't enough even though we are just in the proof of concept phase, we are already getting request for other options. These other options are going to require access to the OS which Apple yea right. We are moving to Android immediately.

Sorry Apple I love you but you loose here.

Answer (score 0):

If your using an Ipad you should consider if it can support the power for the USB thing. Watch this [Using Powered USB Port](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ5PF6NH-GE&feature=relmfu)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about putting the tablet behind another piece of glass/plastic is neat. To then deal with remote controlling, you might consider doing some Bluetooth programming.

My mobile development has been primarily with iOS, so I am biased toward that SDK. I will mention that the data/sync/charge port for iOS has (I believe) never changed. Your Gen 1 iPhone sync cord works on your iPhone 4... and your iPad or iPad 2. So, in terms of third party hardware, you may see more consistency with Apple.

I haven't found a good answer regarding whether it is easier to do Bluetooth programming for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715248/ios-how-to-perform-bluetooth-communication) or [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619850/code-samples-for-android-bluetooth-programming), but I think to stay cost-effective, you might see which one is more open to third-party devices. [Here is an SO post/answer about iOS and third-party Bluetooth devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059362/best-platform-for-bluetooth-applications); I've not found anything on Android regarding third-party Bluetooth remotes, but considering a lot of hardware running Android is third-party, your chances from a naive perspective seem pretty good. Here's the [Android Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).

Buying an iOS or Android handheld to remote control an iOS or Android tablet does seem a bit steep, but then again, maybe not. Cost also depends on your ratio of remotes to tablets. 1:1? 1:N? N:1? N:M?

The [lowest end iPod](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/specs.html) goes for $229 as of May 20, 2011. Android does have more variety in terms of hardware. You may be able to get a [cheap Android phone](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=cheap%20android%20phone&btnG=Search#q=cheap%20android%20phone&hl=en&sa=G&prmd=ivnsrfd&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&ei=lPXWTdWeFKXu0gGm35HBBw&ved=0CEcQrQQ&fp=cd33777547d3ea07&biw=1294&bih=899) with no service plan to act as a Bluetooth remote for an Android tab.

Comment: Software wise, Flash or Silverlight, or even using something like JQuery Mobile would work.  We've already identified that 10" would be the ideal form factor.  Could go a little bigger, but not much.  Also, the device must be touch screen and no keyboard.  So first thought is a tablet.  I've started to look into touch screens that would connect to perhaps a Linux PC, but that will drive the per unit cost up a bit - still need to research it I think.

Answer (score 0):

We manufacture tablet kiosks that support both android and iPad devices. In fact we are the only iPad kiosk that has achieved apple approval.

Generally speaking i think you will have an easier time with an iPad as the software and hardware will remain more consistent over time. Which is important if you have to change out a fault unit or deploy more kiosks 6 months or year from now when the original device is no longer manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a solution for the kiosk mode using iPad here [Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app)

I am afraid that I don't really know for Android if the same thing is possible.

To address the issue of crashing applications you can use an exception trampoline (see discussion here https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=275) to catch the crash and reboot your app.

If the entire device is restarted however then other apps that are on the device can be started and will subsequently be locked in.

To answer your other points:

- You can use a configuration profile to control network access. Force it to use a VPN or Proxy that only allows your custom app with embedded credentials to use. That way other network access can be prevented.
- Your concern over future compatibility is spot on. The Android marketplace is so fragmented then maintaining a fleet is difficult.
- If you have an app that is behaving as a server and is locked in then remote control is possible.